# C# How to get image from array of bytes (blob converted into array of bytes)?

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, compression

We are saving a picture from android app to MySQL blob. Now we want to get that image in C#. Can anyone suggest a equivalent code for C#? We want to show original image. I have successfully retrieved data from database. it is returning me array of bytes.I have tried lots of methods but I am getting image with small size and with low quality

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
   byte[] imageBytes= baos.toByteArray();
   String encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
   return encodedImage;
}
```

I have tried below code
C# code

```
byte[] dbBytes = (byte[])dtCameraImage.Rows[0]["Image"];

                if (dbBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    string s_unicode2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dbBytes);

                    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s_unicode2);

                    if (bytes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                        {
                            img = new Bitmap(ms);
                            //img.Save("C:\\Newfolder\\test2.jpg");
                            imgImagePopup.Source = ConvertToImgSource(img);
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: Do not post an image of your code. Post the relevant code in the question

Comment: _"We want to show original image."_ - Impossible because JPEG is a lossy format.

Comment: So you're asking how to get data from a database in C#?  Start with some tutorials on exactly those technologies...

Comment: Added code. I have successfully retrieved data from database. this is not a issue. If I change JPEG to PNG does it improve the quality of images?

Comment: I'd suggest to first try without compression. If the resulting data is too big, then deal with compression.

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
Use PNG insted of JPEG.
With JPEG the original BMP image is lost. see Fildors comment.

To do it in C#:

- get the data out of the Database
- reverse the steps you did in Java in C#
- save or display the image

You normally do not need to "decompress" the image back to BMP.

[edit2]
Did you tried `Image.FromStream` ?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "reverse the steps you did in Java in C#" => Here is the problem @AjayThakare You can only "reverse" to display the JPEG. The compression step is irreversible (using jpeg) even with 100% quality. That's because in the process, there are several steps that are losing information. For example quantization.

Comment: Added code. I do not want to do my work from anyone. I have tried a lot but not getting expected result. So why asking the question on forum. Database is not issue just added to understand exact scenario. In java bitmap is compressed but there is no decompress in C#. so why asking

Comment: maybe that helps to get the "image" https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx